# Tabbing behavior and link submit buttons

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I've built a form which uses a link, coupled with a jQuery command to submit the form, as the submit button. Everything works dandy except for tabbing — when navigating the form with the tab key the submit link just gets skipped over. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Examples of your code would be nice to better understand your problem

Comment: I thought it was pretty clear

Comment: I'm also guessing the link is DOM inserted which probably gave it a higher tabindex than the other elements

Comment: I'm not sure how the code would be useful, it's really nothing special, but here it is:

Comment: HTML: <a class="pledge_form_btn" href="javascript:null(0);"><span><?php echo $options['pledge_btn_text']; ?></span></a>

Comment: JQUERY:      $('.pledge_form_btn').click(function() {
      $('div#pledge_form_content form').submit();
     });

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it's the tabindex (or at least it might be).  If you tab long enough do you eventually get to the correct link?  If you do you can just manually set the tab index with [element.tabIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.tabIndex)

Comment: No, sadly, it never goes to the link. I've tried tabindex, but that only works on form elements, and won't work for links (at least according to one website I found when tabindex didn't work).

Comment: My own guess is that, because the submit action is done by jQuery onclick, the browser isn't recognizing the link as part of the form. So, perhaps a more specific question would be how to make sure the browser knows that this is the submit button?

Comment: have you tried puting the javascript in an onclick attribute rather then the href attribute? (leaving href as # or whatnot)

Comment: Bummer, still doesn't change anything. It seems like I ought to just be able to insert some attribute like type="submit" (which doesn't work, btw), but I can't find anything like that anywhere.

Comment: I was able to tab to it and press enter.  Seems to have worked.

Comment: Perhaps is a browser specific problem? It doesn't work for me in either Safari or Firefox. Haven't tried it in any others.

Comment: could be. I'm using Chrome atm.

Comment: Yep, that must be it. I just tried chrome and it also worked for me, so I guess it's just a browser thing. Thanks for your help!